# Error - data loss - with dhcp client lease - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, dhcp

Since I have upgraded to the latest version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version, I started having an annoying issue with my internet connection over any wireless network I try to connect to. What is happening is if my laptop goes on sleep mode or if I have to leave home and goes to university or somewhere else, when I try to connect to a WiFi network, it doesn't work right away. I might still be connected to wireless network but I have no internet connectivity. This is happening on existing WiFi points I used in the past and on new ones since the upgrade. So what I have to do constantly and multiple times is to execute the dhcp client manually to renew the IP address. looks like it doesn't do that automatically. 
I have to enter through the terminal the command couple of time before it starts working again.

```
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

And what I noticed is that, I receive some errors on the first time I run the command :

```
/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases line 40: numeric minute expected.
renew 1 2018/10/22 08:3lease 
                    ^
/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases line 40: semicolon expected.
renew 1 2018/10/22 08:3lease {
                              ^
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
Corrupt lease file - possible data loss!
```

if it is unsuccessful after doing that, I have to reboot the computer and redo it again until I get a connectivity. I even tried to restart the networking interface through

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

and it doesn't work !
Is there any permanent solution that I can implement? or is it a bug that came along with the upgrade that is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your file `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` is corrupt. You could look at line 40 mentioned in the error message.

There should be no important information in that file, so you could just clear that file (or first make a copy the content).

Comment: I have this problem on a regular basis. But I only know about the broken file when I issue `sudo dhclient -v` because DNS stopped working again. But then it's too late because it will overwrite the broken file immediately. So I neither know what was wrong nor what caused it. Any idea how to find the culprit?

Comment: @JPT To find out what is wrong, make a copy of the file before you renew the DHCP. Finding the reason is more difficult, the content of the file may contain a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that my "system" `dhclient` went amok. My `syslog` was spammed by `dhclient` desperately trying to fetch an IP.

The first time I realized this problem there were 13 instances of `dhclient` running concurrently. No wonder the leases file was broken and the DHCP server was confused.

My workaround is issue this command manually:

```
ps ax|grep dhclient; sudo killall dhclient; sudo dhclient -v
```

This shows how many `dhclient` are currently running then kills all of them and starts a new one.

I still have the problem that automatic DHCP does not work. I always have to isse `dhclient` manually using the command above. But I never again had more than one `dhclient` already running.

There are still a few questions unsolved:

- How exactly does `dhclient` work? Does it fork into background when called from console?
- Who is responsible for starting and monitoring the "system" `dhclient`?